# Converting tfs branches into git branches

Tags: git, tfs, version-control

We have our code on tfs with branches like this:

dev

- release_1
- release_2
- release_3

Now we are trying to migrate our code to git, and use git-tfs tool for it.

When we use "git tfs clone" command on "dev" with "--branches=all" it converts everything into repo with a single branch master, that contains release_1, release_2... as folders inside repo.

Is this normal behavior?(were expecting repo with many branches). And if, yes, is there a way to convert such structure to normal git repo with branches? or may be we are doing something wrong?

Comment: Is "Dev" the name of the team project or is it a branch that acts as a parent to the "release_x" branches?

Comment: To use `--branches=all` option for git tfs clone, you should convert all the folder into branches as the document https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/commands/clone.md#clone-all-the-branches-and-merge-changesets said. Besides, you can also clone the TFVC branches into separate git repo, and then merge the git repositories together.

Comment: @James Reed - Yes, "Dev" is parent branch. Thanks.

Comment: @Marina - MSFT - yeah i knew that, and everything works fine with small test projects and branches. I don't need to merge git repositories, i need to get repo with branches like a have now in tfs. Thanks.

Comment: Guys, today its working, and i didn't changed anything, just magic. but not for all branches and the problem seems to be known here
https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/461

thanks to everyone.